# Using the contents of the clipboard in an email body

Tags: vb.net, outlook, cpu-word

in VB.Net I am trying to copy the entire contents of a Word Document and then paste the clipboard into an email body.  Populating the clipboard was easy but I am not sure how to use it in the contents of the email body.

here is my failed code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim objWord
    Dim wordPath
    Dim currentDocument
    Dim myRange

    wordPath = "C:\Users\user.on.computer\OneDrive\_My Clients\_Older Clients\ASG\Trip Reports\ASG TOOLS 20170320 BAM3.docx"
    objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Documents.Open(wordPath, False, True)
    currentDocument = objWord.Documents(1)

    myRange = currentDocument.Range
    myRange.WholeStory
    myRange.Copy

    Dim objOutl, objMailItem, strEmailAddr
    objOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    objMailItem = objOutl.CreateItem(0)


    Dim iData As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()

    strEmailAddr = "me@somewhere.com"
    objMailItem.Recipients.Add(strEmailAddr)

    objMailItem.HTMLBody = iData.GetData("String")

    objMailItem.Subject = "Testing Process"
    objMailItem.Attachments.Add(wordPath)
    objMailItem.Save
    objMailItem = Nothing
    objOutl = Nothing
    objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am hoping its an easy fix, thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it

```
With objMailItem.GetInspector
    .WordEditor.Content.Paste
    .Close 0
End With
```